# Making a small modification to a LaTeX environment

Tags: latex

I've been using `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` throughout my LaTeX document, but the default styling is ugly; namely, the figures are all left-aligned.  Is there a way to redefine the "figure" environment so it automatically inserts some centering commands such as like this?:

```
\begin{figure} \begin{center}
\end{center} \end{figure}
```

Sure, I could use `\newenvironment` to define a "cfigure" environment, but that's undesirable.  I don't want to go through and change all my "figures" to "cfigures" (and then later realise I wanted all the figures to be right-aligned and have to rename them all to "rfigures").

I could use `\renewenvironment`, but then I'd have to dig through the LaTeX source to find what the "figure" environment was originally defined as copy/paste it in.

I *almost* found what I wanted at [this blog post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/plaintex/expandafter/), but the example there was for a command, not an environment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
\let\oldfigure\figure
\def\figure{\oldfigure\centering}
```

Another solution which works with the optional arguments.

**Fixed.**

```
\let\oldfigure\figure
\let\oldendfigure\endfigure
\def\figure{\begingroup \oldfigure}
\def\endfigure{\centering \oldendfigure \endgroup}
```

**Fixed 2.** It does work well with any options and any rules and `\par` inside.

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldfigure\figure
\def\figure{\@ifnextchar[\figure@i \figure@ii}
\def\figure@i[#1]{\oldfigure[#1]\centering}
\def\figure@ii{\oldfigure\centering}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because figure takes an optional argument (like [htbp] that will be broken by this redefinition.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tested your new solution? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: (By the way, I made the same mistake when I first started redefining the environment `;)` )

Comment: The second solution doesn't work for me either.  The figures aren't being centered.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Fixed. It is necessary to move "\centering" down.

Comment: Still won't work for input like `\begin{figure}\rule{4em}{4em}\par\rule{4em}{4em}\end{figure}`; this only applies `\centering` to the last paragraph. Also, you don't need the groups.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for a `figure*`?

Answer (score 7):

As noted in another answer, you can't do the old trick of prepending commands to the end of the `\figure` macro because that will mess up the optional argument processing.

If an environment doesn't have arguments then it will work fine, but otherwise there's no straightforward way of doing this.

For your problem with the figures, try loading the floatrow package:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
```

If will centre the content of your figures automatically.

**Update:** If you don't want to load a package, here's some code that will also do it. Note that it's specific to the `figure` environment, but the basic theme is: copy the original definition, parsing arguments the same way, then add whatever code you need at the end.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][\fps@figure]{
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@float{figure}[#1]} 
  \@tempa\centering
}{
  \end@float
}
\makeatother
```

The `\edef` is required to fully expand `\fps@figure` before it's passed to the `\@float` macro.

Comment: I did ask for a solution that doesn't involve copying the definition, but I tried this anyway and got an undefined command "\fps".

Comment: I explained why it's impossible to do it (in this case) without copying the definition. You need to add `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` around the code (I added this to my example) when (re)defining commands containing `@`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
\newenvironment{centeredfigure}{\begin{figure}\begin{center}}{\end{center}\end{figure}}
```

Note: untested.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this approach but you should use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, because the latter adds additional vertical padding that isn't necessary.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want to redefine it under another name.